# avoid pass function refernce in other object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

anyone can suggest me how to call parse without use parseFunc as argument in aj.call ? I think it's a bad idea "override" prototype.parse and then pass as argument, why cant use the  aj.parse directly?
ecma5 because it works in Iternet Explorer compatibility mode on (old IE version)
Thanks

```
function AjaxFactory(){

}

AjaxFactory.prototype.async = false;
AjaxFactory.prototype.method = "GET";

AjaxFactory.prototype.parse = function (result){
    return result;
}

AjaxFactory.prototype.call = function (callActionUrl, data, parseFunc){
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: callActionUrl,
            method: this.method,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
               return parseFunc.call(this,result);
            },
            async: this.async
        });
}

/*
 * es:*/
var myParser = function (result){
    return "my parser of " + result;  
}

var url = "";
var aj = new AjaxFactory();
aj.parse = myParser;
aj.async =false;
aj.method = "GET";
alert(aj.call("url",{}, aj.parse));
```

*add 08 Dec 2020

I have also this question: the return value does not return when i do alert(aj.call) so i change as below. But i suppose: does it working when async is true? Maybe 'return outreturn'  can be executed before that 'success' was called..can you suggest me? Maybe can i use the result directly in the parse function..right? Thanks

```
AjaxFactory.prototype.call = function (callActionUrl, data, parseFunc){
   var outreturn;
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: callActionUrl,
            method: this.method,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
               outreturn =parseFunc.call(this,result);
            },
            async: this.async
        });
return outreturn;  <-- this can be wrong when async true 
}
```

Comment: Since `AjaxFactory` is a class, you have to refer to it's props as `this.prop`, where `prop` in your case is `parse`. If it still doesn't work, add default values to your `AjaxFactory` function and that will surely handle it as a `class`

Comment: @kpm you suggest to write "return parse(result)" ? this. not work because i'm in the jQuery object, so i have to set context to this (= the caller).

Comment: I was suggesting to call `this.parse.call(this,result);`  Here `this` should refer to `AjaxFactory` and you don't have to pass a callback function

Comment: "*I think it's a bad idea "override" prototype.parse and then pass as argument*" - it's not really bad, just unnecessary. You can (and should) just do `aj.call("url", {}, myParser);`

Comment: "*Maybe 'return outreturn' can be executed before that 'success' was called*" - [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)."*Maybe can i use the result directly in the parse function..right?*" - yes, you should. Just put the `alert` call directly in your `myParser` function. Don't have it `return` anything.